# Real time database Firebase, I fetch the data once with VUE 3 but when changing tab I get error undefined( current user)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs3

thank you in advance for reading me, so I have an app with a connection to a realtime database from firebase. Early I was having the issue that my data was not displaying and I thought I solved it with an v-if="mydataresponse" and the main container and then before the v-for after that I could see the information on the web, however when navigating in another router, and going back I lost the data, and I got a message error Cannot read property 'favorites' of undefiened. Also I'm not sure if the way I am getting the information it is the best, so suggestion are welcome.

Here is my component to list the fav from the database:

```
<template>
<div id="fav-view" v-if="response && getDbvalue">

<div class="caps s-m-b-8 add-line-down"><strong>Favorites</strong></div>

  <div v-if="favStatus == 0"  class="my-notify-info">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
&#160;&#160;You don't have favorites yet</div>

<div v-else>
   <div v-if="getDbvalue.length && response.allArticles" class="w-dyn-items"> 
            <Notification
              v-for="article in displayFav"
              :key="article.id"
              :articleTitle="article.articleTitle"
              :notId="article.id"
              :articleSubtitle="article.categoryName.categoryName"
             >
            </Notification>
 </div>
</div>

<!---button @click="test">Test button</button--->

</div>
    
</template>

<script>
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/database'  
import { request } from '../headlesscms'

import Notification from "../components/content/notification.vue";



const HOMEPAGE_QUERY = `
  {
  allArticles{
    id
    articleTitle
    articleDate
    articleContent
    articleFavorite
    categoryName {
      categoryName
    }
    articleTags {
      articleTag
    }
  }
}
`;

export default {
  data() {
    return {
     
      response: null,
 
    };
  },
  components: {
  Notification,
  },

  computed:{
        getCurrentUser(){
              if (firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) 
              var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
              return currentUser;

        } ,   
        getDbvalue(){
              var dbValues = [];
              var favRef = firebase.database().ref("userfav");
              favRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
              snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
              var key = childSnapshot.key;
              var data = childSnapshot.val();
              dbValues.push({key: key, id: data.id, favorites: data.favorites});
                });
              });
              return dbValues;
        },
          displayFav(){
              var dbValue = this.getDbvalue;          
              var filteredFav = dbValue.find(x => x.id === this.getCurrentUser).favorites;    
              return  this.response && this.response.allArticles.filter(a => filteredFav.includes(a.id));   
            },
favStatus(){
      var userFavstatus = this.getDbvalue.find(x => x.id === this.getCurrentUser).favorites.length; 
      return userFavstatus;
    },

  },
  methods:{
    test(){
         var dbValue = this.getDbvalue;
      var filteredFav = dbValue.find(x => x.id === this.getCurrentUser);
      //var test = this.response && this.response.allArticles.filter(a => filteredFav.includes(a.id));   
        console.log(filteredFav)
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
   try {
     this.response = await request({
       query: HOMEPAGE_QUERY,
       variables: {
         limit: 15,
       }
     });
   } catch (e) {
     this.error = e;
   }
   this.loading = false;
 },
};

</script>
```

So, to give more precise I suspect the issue should be coming from this line:

```
var filteredFav = dbValue.find(x => x.id === this.getCurrentUser).favorites;
```

In general I tried a different approach, to implement a workaround I found here to load the components before the database in the main.js, but just got more errors, so any suggestions are welcome. Let me know if you need something else : )

Comment: `this.getCurrentUser` is a function, so you need to call it with parentheses: `this.getCurrentUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

it's likely because `dbValue.find(x => x.id === this.getCurrentUser)` might not return an object.

In addition to fixing that, you should validate whether the result returns an object.

```js
var match = dbValue.find((x) => x.id === this.getCurrentUser());
if (!match) return; // exit no additional processing, might need to change handling
var filteredFav = match.favorites;
```

---

update

I would suggest updating the computed property names and drop the `get`, which makes it a bit confusing. Also the way you have the conditional defined, it's a bit troublesome.

I've reformatted it to make it more clear, but this is just a bit

```js
computed:{
  getCurrentUser(){
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) {
      var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    }
    return currentUser; // < currentUser value variable does not exist if conditional is false
  } ,
}
```

... but that's just for readability. The real issue is likely because the authentication is a asynchronous function that hasn't resolved yet the first time you load the component. I believe the common way that gets handled is through vuex, since knowing whether the user is logged in is something that you likely want accessible throughout the app, not just in the component, so I would suggest you have that globally accessible as-well either through vuex or some other method.

for example, you could setup a `firebaseUtil.js` file with (using `ref`)

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import { ref } from "vue";

export const currentUser = ref(null);
export const auth = ref(null);

export function signIn() {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((authResult) => {
      auth.value = authResult;
      currentUser.value = authResult.user;
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
    });
}
```

You can then access these values in a reactive way, so in you `.vue` component

```js
import {currentUser} from "firebaseUtil.js"

/...
setup(){
  return {currentUser}
}
```

If you don't want to use a setup function (though you can use it with class-based components) you could even add something like this `this.firebaseCurrentUser = currentUser` to an on mounted hook. The benefit of using `ref` is that it remains reactive, so once the authentication resolves, the component will reload.

Comment: Hello Daniel, sorry for the late replay,  regarding the solution I read somewhere in the documentation that you can call a computed without the (), also here an example https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-a-computed-method-in-another-computed-method/31491. However I did implement the suggestion anyways :) and i had the same result, so I what I did was, I did create an store with vuex, add the object with the database values to a getters, and call it from this page (action and getter) now I don't get the error in the console and navigate in the router without lose the info, HOWEVER ...

Comment: The first time I access to the app, by example after login, I cannot see the data and I get the "undefined" again, after clicking any link router and going back to the page I can see the data and error is gone. Like there is a delay of the response, not sure if I should create a new topic or update the code in the main question.

Comment: You're right, I missed that `getCurrentUser` was a computed, the `()` is not needed and I removed it from the answer. It's a good idea though to follow [common js nomenclature](https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-naming-conventions), such as using verbs as method prefixes.